# Send get request with arduino to ASP.NET webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services, azure, arduino, wifi

I created a webservices in ASP .NET, that i published on azure, with this function

```
public string GetObject(int id)
{
   return ("it is a test !");
}
```

when i enter the right URL, it works.
But when i try to send the request with arduino (based on ethernetclient example), it does not work.

the arduino code :

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFlyHQ.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

WiFly wifly;

char ssid[] = "myssid";
char password[] = "mypass";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  wifly.begin(&Serial, NULL);

    if (!(wifly.setSSID(ssid))) {
      Serial.println("Fail to set ssid"); 
    }
/*    if (!(wifly.setKey(password))) {
      Serial.println("Fail to set passPhrase"); 
    } */
    if (!(wifly.setPassphrase(password))) {
      Serial.println("Fail to set passPhrase");
    }
    wifly.enableDHCP();
    if (wifly.join()) {
      Serial.println("Joined wifi network");
    } else {
      Serial.println("Failed to join wifi network");
    }

    if (wifly.open(myurl.azurewebsites.net)) {
      wifly.println("GET /api/object/123 HTTP/1.0");
      wifly.println("");
    }
    else
      Serial.println("Connection failed");
}

void loop() {
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }
}
```

The connection to the ssid works. But it blocks on wifly.open(). But, if I put wifly.open("search.yahoo.com") and then wifly.write("GET /search?p=50+km+in+miles HTTP/1.0"), ALL WORKS !

Do you know why ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: "when i enter the right URL, it works" - What URL are you entering? Also are you using ASP.NET Web API in Azure? I guess not as you have  GetObject() instead of Get().

Comment: I followed a tutorial for this, and they said to put only Get as you said, bu another one said to put GetObject... I did it with ASP .NET and i created a web site on azure for put it online. I am open for all tips ! :)

Comment: I agree that it looks as though what you have should work. Try removing "client.println("Host: azurewebsites.net");" as HTTP 1.0 doesn't require it. Also instead of "client.println("GET /api/object/123 HTTP/1.0");" try "client.println("GET /api/object?id=123 HTTP/1.0");".

Update your question so we can see what your Web Api Controller class looks like; Is GetObject within a controller which inherits from ApiController?

Answer (score 0):

How does EthernetClient get connected with WiFly?  I don't see any calls that connect them. I have done some playing with a WiFly module but I don't see how you use EthernetClient with it.

The WiFly module is the network connection and is accessed via serial. Wouldn't you need to make the request though it, handle the responses with serial processing?

Comment: You are right. I tried an other way. Instead of calling Ethernet Client, I used wifly.open("myurl.azurewebsites.net", 80). And then, wifly.println("GET /api/object/123 HTTP/1.0"). It does not work, but if I use : wifly.open("search.yahoo.com"). And then, wifly.println("GET /search?p=50+km+in+miles HTTP/1.0"), IT WORKS ! I do not understand it...

Comment: does your url work with a basic browser? Connected via the same access point you use for the wifly?